# expand all node in SQL Reporting Service?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

Hi
By default when we try use grouping in reports, in output we had collapsed all node in view but this isn't good.
So after searching I found this solution: "use Toggle Item". but when I set value for this property my report crashed and in result I had no filed value in view.

`which one is the solution? toggle Item or other way?`
(if toggle item is solution post sample as answer)

Comment: @For additional info : i use report builder 2 to make that report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reportbuilder 3.0 you have to edit the group properties and change the visibility option to “Show” when the report is first run.

I don’t know exactly where it is on reportbuilder 2.0 but I would imagine this will put you on the right track

[image: Showing the group properties]